# Do Azure App Service Backups also restore configuration?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, backups

When restoring a backup for an App Service, does it also restore all the configurations like Connection strings and Application settings?
I have looked through the documentation but it is unclear.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the backup only saves the App Service Data.

If you what to save the App Services configuration, the easiest way is by downloading the ARM template.
[image: export template]

You only need to deploy the ARM template if you need to recreate the resource.

Here is the documentation for deploying an ARM template:

- **Azure CLI:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-cli
- **PowerShell**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-powershell
- **Portal**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-portal#deploy-resources-from-custom-template